# Apply a function which operates on specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following data frame (note, it is only for the purpose of illustration, not for the actual problem to solve)

```py
#df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,2,2,2],
#"purchase":[True,False,False,False,True,True],
#"prod":["Apple","Pear","Banana"]*2})

    id  purchase prod
----+-----+--------+
    1   True    Apple
    1   False   Pear
    1   False   Banana
    2   False   Apple
    2   True    Pear
    2   True    Banana
```

and a function to return only the purchased products

```py
def get_prod_purch(df):
    """
    Get products
    """
    x = df["purchase"]
    return df.loc[x]
```

If I run this as a `groupby` it works perfect:

```py
df.groupby("id").apply(get_prod_purch)
#
        id  purchase prod
id  ----+-----+-------+         
1   0   1   True    Apple
2   4   2   True    Pear
    5   2   True    Banana
```

but if I just want to run it on the dataframe

```py
df.apply(get_prod_purch)
#KeyError: 'purchase'

df.apply(get_prod_purch,axis=1)
#KeyError: True
```

Is there a way to run such a function on the dataframe and not the `groupby` i.e

```py
df.apply(some_function)

#Result
    id  purchase prod
----+-----+--------+
    1   True    Apple
    2   True    Pear
    2   True    Banana
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html), because need apply function for all `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.pipe(get_prod_purch))
   id  purchase    prod
0   1      True   Apple
4   2      True    Pear
5   2      True  Banana
```

Or pass `DataFrame` to function like:

```
print (get_prod_purch(df))
   id  purchase    prod
0   1      True   Apple
4   2      True    Pear
5   2      True  Banana
```

If use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function runs per columns or per rows `axis=1`.

Comment: Didt know knew about `df.pipe` - awesome!